# angular.js Sort filter for ng-repeat that uses priorities and object property values

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Consider a JSON object with the following data:

```
{
   "results": [
      { 
         flags: [
            is_special: true // or false, or non-existing
         ],

         type: "typeone" // or typetwo, or non-existing
      },
      ... // repeats
   ]
}
```

What's an efficient way of creating a filter for `ng-repeat="result in json.results"` that orders results:

1. by putting all of the `is_special=true` first, ordered by #2, & #3.
2. by putting all `typeone` before `typetwo`
3. by putting all `typetwo` before all the rest (or without any flags/types).

*Important:* it mustn't fail when some of these properties are non-existent or equal to `""`

Thanks

Comment: Does `flags` always only have 1 item?

Comment: No @tymeJV, can have more. Check for a new restrain I added also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`orderBy` takes an array of arguments, so you can just go down the list:

```
ng-repeat="result in json.results | orderBy: [isSpecial, typeFilter]"


$scope.isSpecial = function(item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < item.flags.length; i++) {
       if (item.flags[i]["is_special"])
            return true;
    }
}

$scope.typeFilter = function(item) {
    item.type == "typeone" ? return 1 : return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the answer. But the 2 functions need some work. `isSpecial` should return 0 for is_special, else maybe 1. `typeFilter` could maybe return 0 for typeone, 1 for typetwo, 2 for rest.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the best way but there is one way of doing this with Underscore JS. Hopefully someone can optimize my code below:

```
// Grab the items that have the flag
first = _.filter(results, function(r)
{
    return r.flags.is_special;
}

// Grab the remainder
remainder = _.where(results, {flags.is_special: false});

// Now grab your second list
second = _.filter(remainder, function(r)
{
    return r.type =='typeone';
});

// Again grab the remainder (and so on)

// Then return your 4 lists
```